# When searching with solr sitecore does not search in the right fields

Tags: content-search, solr

We know that sitecore uses solr dynamic fields so that we don't need to declare all the fields that we have in sitecore separately in the solr schema to get them indexed.

In our case we have a singleline text field 'Meta Title' in sitecore that is indexed as 'meta_title_t' in solr. However, when searching on the field 'meta_title', sitecore sends a query like 'meta_title:*', that is, the _t is not appended to the fieldname that we pass to the solr query. Th reason is maybe that sitecore at search time does not know that 'meta_title' corresponds to the single-line text field 'Meta Title', the mapping seems to be gone.

How could we ensure that sitecore finds the correct mapping and appends the _t at search time? Of course, we could append the _t ourselves when searching, but that seems not very elegant. Or mabe define the field explicitly in sitecore solr configuration?

Comment: Which Sitecore version do you use?

Comment: Also could you confirm that you don't have more than one template with `Meta Title` field? Could you check if your template with `Meta Title`  is indexed?

Comment: Using sitecore version 9.0.1 (rev. 171219). The Meta Title field is defined in a base template that is inherited by several other templates. In the solr console I am seeing the field named 'meta_title_t'.

Comment: Usually the type extension is missed when Sitecore somehow can't resolve a field type. Please have a look at the following article to understand the field type resolving process: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr-field-name-resolution.html